# Can't access instance attributes

Tags: python, composition

I try to use the composition relationship but I can't access to the compound class A:
with this code I'm trying to add to the list of class A,  an object from the class B.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self,X,Y,Z):
        self.X
        self.Y
        self.Z
    def Xreturner(self):
        return self.X
    def Yreturner(self):
        return self.Y
    def Zreturner(self):
        return self.Z

class A:
    def __init(self):
        self.lst=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],]
        self.b=B()
    def add(self): # trying to add b object to the list
        self.lst.append(self.b)
#### TEST####
objA=A()
objA.add(6,7,8)
```

When I test I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/testXYZ.py", line 28, in <module>
    objA.add(6,7,8)
TypeError: add() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: ... you're trying to call `objA.add` with three arguments (plus the implicit `self`) when you have written the method to only take `self`. What are you confused about? (Also, you have a number of other errors in your code.)

Comment: your error is telling you that `def add(self)` takes 1 argument only and you tried to give it 4...... so either accept a list of numbers in that function or 3 extra variables. Plus there's other errors in your code.

Comment: @kiran Please do not edit -- and alter -- the original poster's (OP) intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your class `B` initializer is incorrect:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):  # <== should use snake_case for vars
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Next, your class `A` add should create a new B object and add to the list:

```
    def add(self, x, y, z):
        new_b = B(x, y z)
        self.lst.append(new_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

- The statement `self.X` in the `__init__` method of `B` does nothing. You need to put `self.X = X`.
- You are passing parameters to `add()` but it doesn't take any parameters. Maybe you want to add parameters (in the same way you have some for `__init__` of `X`.
- Maybe you even want to pass parameters to the `__init__` of `A` (instead of to `A`). Then you can pass those to the constructor of `B`.